# How to Call two action from one Command Link?

Tags: pagereference, commandlink, onclick

I have to call 2 URL on click of command Link , one will Record Edit Page URl and Another is different Webserver URl

I have tried two Ways Both are Not Working.....I mean both action is Not Performing

**OPTION 1**

```
<apex:column >
   <apex:commandLink value="Click" action="{!meth1}" target="_blank" onclick="methodInJavascript();"> 
        <apex:param value="{!ll.Mobile__c}" assignTo="{!toMObile}" name="assignvalue" />
   </apex:commandlink>
</apex:column>


 <apex:actionFunction action="{!meth2}" name="methodInJavascript" />
```

Apex Class

```
public PageReference meth2() {
    Pagereference p2 = new  Pagereference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/a0A28000000okkjEAA/e');
p2.setredirect(true);

return p2;
    }


    public PageReference meth1() {
    Pagereference p1 = new Pagereference('https://www.google.com');
p1.setredirect(true);

return p1;
    }
```

Here Only  Meth1() is Executing

**OPTION 2**

```
<apex:column >
   <apex:commandLink value="Click" action="{!meth1}" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://ap2.salesforce.com/a0A28000000okkjEAA/e')"> 
        <apex:param value="{!ll.Mobile__c}" assignTo="{!toMObile}" name="assignvalue" />
   </apex:commandlink>
</apex:column>
```

Pagereference URL will be dynamic....I will be Passing parameters

**'https://ap2.salesforce.com/ ' + a.id + '/e';**

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    <p onclick="openTwoWindows()">Click</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openTwoWindows() 
    {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I've already tried above also it is not working......moreover I've to pass the parameter in the Pagereference

Comment: Have you looked into JavaScript Remoting and the @RemoteAction annotation? You could pass a value back to the controller that way.

Comment: However you end up doing it, this looks like it is beyond what Visualforce provides, and will likely require a bit of JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You can call one action through action and another action through calling actionFuncation on click

Ex-
 <
apex:commandLink value="Click" action="{!action1}" target="_blank" onclick="callActionFuncation"

> apex:actionFunction name="callActionFuncation" action="{!action2}" />

Comment: Please provide a specific reason who down vote the answer. So I can also improve my knowledge if I have given the wrong answer.